# Tuple relational calculus

Tags: turing-complete, tuple-relational-calculus

Is safe tuple relational calculus a turing complete language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's forget about safety. By [Codd's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd's_theorem), relational calculus is equivalent to first order logic. FOL is very limited, it can't express the fact that there's a route from a point A to point B in some graph (it can express the fact that there's a route from a point A to point B in limited length, for example ∃x ∃y ∃z ∃t route(a,x) and route(x,y) and route(y,z) and route(z,t) and route(t,b) means there's a route of length 4).

See [descriptive complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_complexity) for a description of what is the strength of different logics.

Comment: You seem to know more about this than I do, however, why can't the following express that there is a route? 

     edge(x, y) -> route(x, y) 
     edge(x, y) & edge(y, z) -> route(x, z) 

if the graph is represented as a set of facts about edges, i.e. 

     edge(a, b) & edge(b, c) & edge(c, d) 

then the query edge(a, d) will be provable by a FOL theorem prover (e.g. a prolog interpreter).

Comment: You're saying that route is _smallest_ transitive relation satisfying edge(x,y) -> route(x,y). This definition requires least-fixed-point. To define a new relation in tuple calculus, you may use intersection, union, projection... but it is not possible to say "route it is a relation satisfying the following conditions...". You might also quantify over relations, but that's higher-order logic, and quantification is allowed only over individuals in FOL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Its really a useful.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Codd's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_theorem), relational algebra and relational calculus are equivalent.  It is well-known that relational algebra is not Turing Complete, so neither is relational calculus.

**[Edit]** You cannot, for instance, do aggregate operations (such as sum, max) or make recursive queries in relational algebra/calculus.  See [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/cis550/slides/3-alg-calc.ppt) (near the end).

Comment: Either you are wrong or Larry Watanabe is. I have no idea of the topic, but this is getting interesting to watch! (goes to fetch popcorn)

Comment: Now relational algebra not being Turing Complete is more well-known :)

Comment: However, from reading another poster's link to Codd's theorem, relational algebra is not equivalent to relational calculus - relational algebra is essentially equivalent to propositional logic whereas relational algebra is equivalent to FOL.

Comment: @Larry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_calculus - "The relational algebra and the relational calculus are essentially logically equivalent ... This result is known as Codd's theorem."